# Initialize viewControllers from a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController. Using interface builder I'm adding multiple view controllers. These viewControllers are all the same class but the only thing that changes is a paramenter.

I want to extend the UITabBarController so I can add this parameter when the view controllers are initialized but I have no clue how to do this in the UITabBarController extension. Where is the right place to do this???

Comment: Currently you controllers are initialized by 'Interface Builder'. If you want to initialize the controller by yourself and add some parameters as well, it's better to add the controllers from code not from interface builder.

Comment: that makes sense, but there must be a way of adding a parameter... i thought of grabbing the viewcontrollers in the view did load of the tabbar controller and add the parameter there... but i feel that's dirty!

Comment: Take a look at the delegate of `UITabbarController`, there is a function [didSelectViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller?language=objc) you can use that one to set the parameter according to index. But it will be set every time you select an tab index to show.

Answer (score 1):

i also faced issue like that, in which i want to show pop over view controller in fifth tab of tab bar controller,
i used this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if(viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[4]){
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "AfterLogin", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MorePopUpVC")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.delegate = self
        popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
        popover?.sourceView = self.tabBar
        popover?.sourceRect = ((self.orderedTabBarItemViews()).last?.frame)!
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 132)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

this is how i change action of fifth tab,

you can use it like:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR STORYBOARD NAME", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER")
        if(viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[4]){
            vc.type = "PARAMETER YOU WANT"
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
        return false
}
```

i think it help.