# Using CoreData and Dependency Injection - Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, dependency-injection, persistence

I'm trying to learn how to use CoreData and the correct way to implement it, currently I have watched this video on youtube (link below). At the moment it all makes sense, however when I go from one viewController to my HomeVC (which is part of a tab bar controller) I get the below error. Does anyone have any idea as to why? Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYRo3i9z-lM

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    \\ Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented
}
```

**Function to home:**

```
func toHome() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if let destVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarHomeVC") as? UITabBarController {
            if let homeVC = destVC.viewControllers?.first as? HomeVC {
                homeVC.persistenceManager = PersistenceManager.shared
                self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeVC:**

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    var persistenceManager: PersistenceManager

    init(persistenceManager: PersistenceManager) {
        self.persistenceManager = persistenceManager
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

**PersistenceManager:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

final class PersistenceManager {

    private init() {}
    static let shared = PersistenceManager()

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataApp")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    lazy var context = persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with segues then the `UIViewController` is instantiated from the `Storyboard`, which is done through the `init?(coder:)` initializer. You making it unusable makes the `HomeVC` unable to instantiate itself from `Storyboard` since it crashes there.

The property `var persistenceManager: PersistenceManager` makes Swift unable to inherit `init(coder:)` from `UIViewController` ([explanation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)) and so you have to provide one for yourself where you initialize all the variables you added, all to get the `UIViewController` into a usable state.

Try to make `var peristenceManager: PersistenceManager` optional since you assign it later anyway or assign it a default value in the same line or assign it a value during `init?(coder:)` so it is initalized. Also call `super.init(coder:)` inside your `init?(coder:)` since there it loads all the settings from the Storyboard.

With `Storyboard` you can’t give things in any initializer so you have to set it after the initializer did run. You can use a static factory function where you initialize the vc instance, then immediately set what you want and then return the vc in a usable state.

> So how can I make homeVC.persistenceManager = PersistenceManager.shared, into HomeVC(persistenceManager: PersistenceManager.shared) by passing it through the tabBarController straight to HomeVC?

You can’t use that initializer since the only one being called is the `init?(coder:)` initializer. You can change the variable to:

```
var persistenceManager: PersistenceManager!
```

Then you can set the variable after `init(coder:)` was called and you have your instance.

Here the `UITabBarController` initializes the `HomeVC`, [this guy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885514/initialize-viewcontrollers-from-a-uitabbarcontroller) had the same issue, where to initialize his `UIViewController` being embedded, maybe it helps you out. The answer uses a call that is being called before a `UIViewController` is being shown:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // Initialization code here.
    // Also make sure its only called once if you want
}
```

He even constructs the `UIViewController` himself if a certain tab is asked for.

You can ofcourse set it as you do already, since the `UITabBarController` is not shown yet. Keep it simple as you do already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! That certainly makes sense. So how can I make homeVC.persistenceManager = PersistenceManager.shared, into HomeVC(persistenceManager: PersistenceManager.shared) by passing it through the tabBarController straight to HomeVC? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! Really sorry but I'm slightly confused as to what I should do as I'm relatively new to coding. If I remove the init and requiredInit, it works perfectly. Would you recommend I do this? Is it possible for you to write the code as to what you would suggest I do? Many thanks once again!

Comment: @WH48 Removing both initializers and making persistenceManager optional with `var persistenceManager: PersistenceManager! ` should work fine for your case.